Juice GPU "sharing" 24.04
Please see Juice
Juice is a client-server application to permit access to a physical GPU on a Linux host to a MS Win guest under a type 2 hypervisor such as Oracle Virtualbox or Broadcom VMware.  Is there a Juice package for 24.04 or previous Ubuntu releases that will run on 24.04? Has anyone successfully installed and ran both the client and server? If Juice is not readily available for 24.04, is there an alternative methodology/application/s that will enable a MS Win guest under a Type 2 hypervisor with a 24.04 host such that the MS Win "virtual machine" can use the physical GPU on the host?
